# How can I get all regions of the country in the country map chart in Apache Supersets

Tags: apache-superset

I'm working with Apache Supersets. I want to get all regions of the country in the country map. Does Superset provide any function to get it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate a  GeoJSON file  of that country with the required regions. Follow the link below on how to go about it.

https://superset.apache.org/docs/miscellaneous/country-map-tools/